# 3 actions 1 button - OnClick Ontouch OnLongClick

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Im having a problem with logic as to how to go about this.

I require 1 button to do 3 things.

1. On click --play a music file once
2. If held (im guessing OnTouch) the music would play and loop but stop on releasing the thumb.
3. OnLongClick - goes to a new view for user input.

I have been able to implement 1 and 3.

My problem is if i use the onTouchListner it will eventually fire the OnLongClick Event and I think it will try to run the onClick event when I release the touch .

Ant thoughts would apprecieted

Comment: how do you differentiate held with longClick?

Comment: that is exactly my delema

Comment: I am thinking of this solution. onDown would play the sound once and the onRelease(onUp) would not have any action, then set a timer so if the onDown event is held for say 500ms then it would set the play sound to repeat(loop) and fire a stop sound on onrelease.

Comment: @PatrickMcCullagh  how u achived your task ? how u start timer for hold up counter ?

Answer (score 0):

onTouch gives you Motion Event. Thus, you can do a lot of fancy things as it help you separate state of movement. Just to name a few

**ACTION_UP

ACTION_DOWN

ACTION_MOVE**

Those are common actions we usually implement to get desire result such as dragging view on screen.

On the other hand, onClick doesn't give you much except which view user interacts. onClick is a complete event comprising of focusing,pressing and releasing.

For more information on how to handle single and multitouch events in android visit [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html)

Comment: Thank you.. i need the ability to do a straight onClick a onLongClick and a Hold. I think what you are saying is write code so that when the Action_down code it will play the sound looping. Action_up  code would stop the sound. The problem is that I also need just a short click so that the button need not be held. Also how long before the onlongclick event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

So ,what you need to work this situation with ,is "MyGestureListener".
 You can still use what you have implemented Onclick and OnLongClick and instead "OnTouch" I am pretty sure you are meant to use "onDown"/"ON_DOWN".

Here is a list of all the methods you can use: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicGestureDetect/src/com.example.android.basicgesturedetect/GestureListener.html

Hope it helped.

Comment: I have followed your link and am still thinking it through in my brain thank you.

Comment: If you need more detailed help, let me know.

Comment: I am thinking of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You better use option 1 normally,then instead of ontouch use onLongClick and write code for a menu to appear with option 2 and 3.

Cheers! :)

Comment: I am thinking that i could use onClick to fire the sound once. Then use onLongClick to loop the sound and Just use a flag of some sort to determine if i need to change the view.  The only problem I see here is that i need the sound to play continiously until the button is released (i think I am going to to use onTouch action ) my problem is seperating the 3 actions

Comment: unfortunately this will not work as i need a instance play of the sound. If i use longclick this will not be any good for option 2